# MySQL how to calculate between the current entry and the porpoise one

Tags: mysql, grafana

I hope my terminologies are correctly but here goes

I need to calculate the data transferred between entries(MB/s). I have a time series that has the timestamp and sum of the data sent and received as utilisation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5Qx8.png)

Table utilisation has a component called 'network'

```
Time                            utilisation
2021-11-19 11:14:13             291815568369
2021-11-19 11:14:53             291820740719
2021-11-19 11:15:33             291826081965
2021-11-19 11:16:13             291831134637
```

So to get an accurate answer I need to know the difference in time and the difference in utilisation

utilisation rate = (291820740719 - 291815568369 ) / (11:14:53 -11:14:13)

To get the above table I have used this query

```
SELECT
  time AS "time",
  utilisation
FROM hardware
WHERE
  $__unixEpochFilter(time) AND
  component = 'network'
ORDER BY time
```

Comment: What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: For porpoise (a cetacean) read previous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work. The aim is to calculate the data rates up and down.

```
SELECT
  time AS "time",
   ( utilisation - LAG(utilisation,1) OVER ( ORDER BY time) ) /  (  time - LAG(time,1) OVER ( ORDER BY time) ) time_usage
FROM hardware
WHERE
  $__unixEpochFilter(time) AND
  component = 'network'
ORDER BY time
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to calculate the formula between every 2 consecutive rows I would do it with a stored procedure using a cursor (you can read about it here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html

then inside the loop you will do your calculation each time between the new fetched row and the previous one (make sure you deal with the first round)